# What is the explanation of this behavior? (When are functions created?)

Tags: javascript, function

The code in question is simple:

```
console.log("So it begins.");
foo();
function foo() { console.log("In foo()."); }
console.log("So it ends.");
```

Why does `foo()` execute, before it is defined (retrospective edit: in Chrome and Safari)?

I tinkered with this a bit, testing the following code in Chrome, Safari and Firefox:

```
javascript:foo();function foo() { alert("Oh."); }
```

An alert is displayed in Chrome and Safari, while Firefox remains silent.

Is there any explanation for this surprising, inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While others explained the "hoisting" behavior of functions (I personally find calling it *context preparation* or *pre-processing* more clear than *hoisting*) the reason of the different behavior of Firefox remains unanswered.

To start with, you should know the difference between a Function Declaration and a *Function Statement*.

A Function Declaration, as in your example can happen only in two places, in global code (outside of any function) and directly within the Function Body of another function, for example:

```
function foo () {}

function bar () {
  function baz() {}
}
```

All the above functions are valid Function Declarations.

The ECMAScript Specification doesn't allow to define Function Declarations in other places for example within Blocks:

```
if (true) {
  function foo () {}
}
```

The above function *should* give you a `SyntaxError` exception, but most implementations are benevolent, and they will still pre-process (hoist) the function, even if the actual function is not reachable (e.g. `if (false) { function bar() {} }`).

In Firefox, *Function Statements* are allowed, meaning that the function definition actually happens when the control reaches that specific statement, for example:

```
if (true) {
  function foo () { return true; }
} else {
  function foo () { return false; }
}
```

Executing `foo();` after the above statements, in Firefox will produce `true`, because the first branch of the `if` statement is actually executed.

In other browsers, `foo();` produces `false` because all the functions are pre-processed when entering the execution context, and the last one will take precedence, even if the `false` branch of the `if` statement is *never* reached.

The Firebug console, executes its code wrapping it inside a `try-catch` block, that's why the function is not available *before* its declaration.

If you try on the console:

```
console.log(typeof f); // "undefined"
function f () {}
```

You will see that `f` isn't prepared yet, but if you wrap your code inside a function, you will see the expected behavior:

```
(function () {
  console.log(typeof f); // "function"
  function f () {}
})();
```

Again, that's because now `f` is defined as a Function Declaration, since it exist in the body of the anonymous function, and is not part of an statement Block.

Comment: Thanks for the effort put into breaking this down, appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Javascript delarations always will be moved to the top. It's called **hoisting**:

- Twitter Engineer (Ben Cherry) on that topic:
  http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/
- http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#function.scopes

Example that should work in all browsers:
http://jsbin.com/abelus/edit

Comment: Firstly, thanks. Secondly, no, it does not work the same in all browsers - at least at the time of writing. I have tested the example code you linked to on Firefox 6.0.2, and no "hello" is displayed.

Comment: @maligree, that really surprised me. This example works in Firefox 6: http://jsbin.com/abelus/2/edit. It seems to be a problem with jsbin. jsFiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/vVhAc/

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are noticing is called [function hoisting](http://elegantcode.com/2011/03/24/basic-javascript-part-12-function-hoisting/).

In a nutshell, functions that are defined using the syntax `function foo() { ... }` are "hoisted" to the top of the scope in which they are defined, thus allowing them to be called before being defined.

With that being said, this is an obscure part of JavaScript. It would not surprise me if there are differences in how browsers implement it (particularly if you are using an older version of firefox).

Comment: +1 for hoisting, -1 for the example; the recursion works because the existence of `bar()` and `foo()` is detected at runtime (e.g. when calling the functions `bar` and `foo`.)

Comment: @Matt, well I'll be damned. You're right. I guess I'll remove the example :)